# How to proportion collapsible items in a flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have a 3-panel page built with flexbox. It looks like this:

[image]

If I expand the second section, the first section will collapse and it'll look like this:

[image]

This is great, but I want it so that the first section to not automatically close when the second section opens up. Ideally, both the first and second section take up the same amount of height (50/50).

```
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open1</a>
        <div>text 1</div>    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open2</a>
        <div>text 2</div>    
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open3</a>
      <div>text 3</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li {
  background:gray;
  padding:10px 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff0ed;
}
ul li:first-child{
  border-top: none;
}

ul a {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul .wrap {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

ul .wrap div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li.active {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul li.active .wrap div {
  display: block;
}
```

How could I achieve this?

[CODEPEN here](https://codepen.io/Scoba/pen/ZeJeVX)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `toggleClass` that will remove class on the clicked element if it already exists otherwise it will add the class.

```js
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  flex-direction: column;
}

ul li {
  background: gray;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  border-top: 2px solid #fff0ed;
}

ul li:first-child {
  border-top: none;
}

ul a {
  background: green;
  display: block;
  padding: 5px;
}

ul .wrap {
  background: #000;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
  color: #fff;
}

ul .wrap div {
  display: none;
  padding: 20px;
}

ul li.active {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}

ul li.active .wrap div {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="active">
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open1</a>
      <div>text 1</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open2</a>
      <div>text 2</div>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div class="wrap">
      <a href="#">open3</a>
      <div>text 3</div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can control it using Javascript:

```
$('li').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $this.on('click', function(){
    if ($this.hasClass('active')) $this.removeClass('active');
    else $this.addClass('active');
  });
});
```

Shorter:

```
 $('li').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this);
  
  $this.on('click', function(){
    $this[$this.hasClass('active') ? 'removeClass' : 'addClass' ]('active');
  });
});
```